# grails how to assert redirect action

Tags: grails, testing

My controller has a function like this:

```
def go() {
...
redirect(action: 'someOtherAction')
}
```

In my integration test, how would I assert that the controller did what I thought it should do?

```
assertEquals 'someOtherAction', controller.????
```

These both give null values:

```
controller.response.redirectedUrl
controller.modelAndView.viewName
```

EDIT:

Capture of response instance:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're getting to your `redirect`? Looks like a `render` instead.

Comment: Definitely a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

If your test is using grails 2.0 style `@TestFor` annotations, you should be able to do this:

```
controller.go()
assert response.redirectedUrl == '/someUrl/someOtherAction'
```

The response is not a property of the controller; the test annotation adds it to the test class itself.

Comment: Nope, the redirectedUrl is still null.  I've attached a screenshot of the response object.  It works fine in production and redirects to the action, I just can't get this part of the test to execute.